# Updating a textbox in main GUI from a thread (created on button click) in cli

Tags: c++-cli

I am very new with C++/CLI, which is based on c#. I have a main GUI form.

```
public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
```

On clicking a button in the from I am creating a thread using   `CreateThread`. Code as following:

```
private: System::Void button3_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
{

HANDLE h1;

h1 = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)thread1,0, 0, &threadID1);

}
```

Now my problem is I need to update a `TextBox` in `Myform` from the thread. Can anybody please tell me how to do it in cli?

Comment: Is it necessary for your project to use native WinAPI `CreateThread` method for threading?

Comment: @SlawomirOrlowski : It is not necessary to use WinAPI CreateThread.

Comment: @SlawomirOrlowski I am able to use ' Thread^ oThread = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(&thread1));  ' this way also

Comment: Fall in the pit of success with the BackgroundWorker class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is safe to use .NET `Thread^` in this scenario. Inside your `thread1` method use `Control::BeginInvoke` or `Control::Invoke` like @AlexF mentioned. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-make-thread-safe-calls-to-windows-forms-controls) you have an example from C#.